# LG Sport Watch - Call Audio To Bluetooth Headset Instead of Watch Speaker

Tags: audio, calls, lg, bluetooth-audio, android-wear

I have a LG Sport Smartwatch that I have been enjoying a lot. However, one very annoying thing is the way it handles calls. If I make a call from the watch the audio comes out of the watch speaker and I have to talk into the watch. I would instead prefer to use my Bluetooth headset (I have the kind that sits on your neck so they are basically always with me) to make phone calls from my watch.

I figure this way I can make the the audio from calls made from the my phone got to my watch and still be able to use the headset to talk and listen that way as well as make the call from the watch and have it work the same way.

I do not know if I am just not configuring it correctly or not or if this is just not possible.

My phone is a Note 8, if that matters at all.

Comment: I didn't quite follow your second paragraph. Are you saying you want to use the headset regardless of whether you start the call from the phone screen or the watch screen?